# Unable to select durable function in Azure Logic app editor

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-durable-functions

I have created a python durable function
[image]

So there is a trigger function(HTTP) - that should be accessible from Logic app, orchestrator function, and activity.
However, if I want to select this function in a logic app I cannot see it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to see the HTTP Trigger functions where the route is set to null.

To reproduce we have created 2 HTTP functions

**Function1 where the route is set to null**

[image]

**Function2 where the route is not set to null**

[image]

**In my logic app**

[image]

Comment: In my case this is a python code and also this is a part of a durable function that maybe has some custom configuration.